# Sympy returns a ConditionSet object when solving an equation, while TINspire returns a numerical value

Tags: sympy, solver, integral

Here is my python code:

```
import sympy as sym

x = sym.Symbol('x')
f = -0.077 * sym.Pow(x - 35.80, 2) + 100

f_prime = f.diff(x)

f_integrate = sym.integrate(sym.sqrt(1 + sym.Pow(f_prime, 2)), x)
```

I want to be able to write this integral and solve it with Sympy (so, I want to isolate the variable b).
[image]

**UPDATE**
Here is now my code.

```
f_integrate = sym.integrate(sym.sqrt(1 + sym.Pow(f_prime, 2))-c, (x, 0, b))

g = 100
for i in range(10, 72):
    bi = sym.nsolve(f_integrate.subs(c,i), g)
    g = bi
return g
```

This code work with the initial function I wrote (f(x)= -0.077 * sym.Pow(x - 35.80, 2) + 100), but with pretty much any other function, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Dragon_Ball_-_Film_3_-_Effect - Test avec les bézier.py", line 543, in <module>
    drawManager(line.copy())
  File "Dragon_Ball_-_Film_3_-_Effect - Test avec les bézier.py", line 199, in drawManager
    t = createT(FU, f, x, distanceNextSyllable)
  File "Dragon_Ball_-_Film_3_-_Effect - Test avec les bézier.py", line 107, in createT
    print(getPosition(f, x, 0, distanceNextSyllable))
  File "Dragon_Ball_-_Film_3_-_Effect - Test avec les bézier.py", line 95, in getPosition
    bi = sym.nsolve(f_integrate.subs(c,i), g)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sympy\utilities\decorator.py", line 88, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 2937, in nsolve
    x = sympify(findroot(f, x0, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mpmath\calculus\optimization.py", line 985, in findroot
    raise ValueError('Could not find root within given tolerance. '
ValueError: Could not find root within given tolerance. (5.9604644775390625e-8 > 2.16840434497100886801e-19)
Try another starting point or tweak arguments.
```

Answer (score 0):

The sympy solution seems to be correct, at least [wolframalpha.com](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=systems+of+equations+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation1%22%7D+-%3E%22y%3DN%5BIntegrate%5BSqrt%5B%28Power%5B%2813783%2F2500+-+77*x%2F500%29%2C2%5D%2B1%29%5D%2Cx%5D%5D%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+%7B%7B%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation2%22%7D+-%3E%22x%3D0%22) gives the same result for the integral.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an older version of SymPy that allowed one to write `integrate(Eq(x, y), x)`. The way to do this now is to write `integrate(x - y, x)`. Doing so for your equation, and using `nsolve` to solve for the numerical value of `b`, after supplying a value for c, looks like this:

```
>>> from sympy.abc import b, c
>>> fc = integrate(sqrt(1 + f_prime**2)-c, (x,0,b))
>>> nsolve(fc.subs(c, 10), 111)
186.052268133373
```

If you have a range of c values to test, use the last solution for a given c as the guess for the next c. e.g. to calculate b for c in [10, 409]

```
g = 100
for i in range(10, 410):
    bi = nsolve(fc.subs(c,i), g)
    g = bi
```

(This takes about 12 seconds on a fairly slow computer.)

Comment: Hi, I tough about it and I realize that my question is a  x/y problem.

I edited my question

Comment: Hi, thank you. I don't understand what is the 111.
I have looked at the documentation, but I still don't understand it. https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html
Could you explain to me why we need the 111?

Finally, how the we specify that the value that the nsolve return need to be greater than 1 (because, in some case, we can have more than one possibility)? Example where there is more than 1 possibility: https://i.imgur.com/IAuY9a1.png
Thank you

Comment: The 2nd arg is an initial guess which must be close to the actual root -- how close depends on the equation being solved. In this case, 111 was close enough to 186 to allow the solver to find the root.

Comment: I can't do an guess, because the integral is not always equal to 10. I can only affirm that my result is greater than 1.

Comment: Check out "first order continuation". Starting from a value (like c=0) where you know the answer (e.g. about 71 -- found with `solve(fc.subs(c,0))`) and then increase c a little and use the 71 as the initial guess for the next value of c (and so on).

Comment: nsolve take a lot of ressource to resolve it, so if I need to do "try error", it will be pretty long. I have like 400 integral I need to make the calculation and there are pretty much.

Comment: See answer update -- it's pretty fast doing what I suggest.

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion, but if I try with any other function, I get an error. I updated my question so you can see my code.

Comment: The code you show (other than the `return` not in a function runs as expected and generates no errors for me. Perhaps you defined c or b as something other than a symbol.